# In Tornado, how to handle two different queries and send the result to browser?

Tags: python, sqlite

This is ColsHandler in Tornado.

```
class ColsHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        try:        
            x = int(self.get_argument('x'))
            y = int(self.get_argument('y'))
            v = int(self.get_argument('v'))
            crl = int(self.get_argument('crl'))
            crl_type = int(self.get_argument('crl_type'))

            DB.update_cols(x,y,v,crl,crl_type)
            data = DB.get_data()            

            self.write(json.dumps({'success': 1, 'data': data}))
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
            self.write(json.dumps({'success': 0}))
```

I receive the arguments and try to handle it in order to extract appropriate results with sqlite3. When front page is loading, this query is important.

```
def get_data(self):
    cols = self.get_cols()
    col_type = self.get_cols_type()

    x = cols['xs'][cols['x']]       #Customer_type
    y = cols['ys'][cols['y']]       #Region
    v = cols['vs'][cols['v']]       #Year

    crl_x = col_type['crl'][col_type['crl_x']]    #Corporate
    crl_y = col_type['crl_type'][col_type['crl_y']]    #Belgium

    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""
        SELECT %s, %s, SUM( %s )
        FROM data
        GROUP BY %s , %s
    """ % ( x, y, v, x, y))
    data = {'Total': 0}
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        x = row[0]
        y = row[1]
        data['Total']+=row[2]
        data[x][y]=row[2]
    return data
```

I need another query to extract different result in details. So I wrote this query.

```
cur.execute("""
        SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s SUM( %s )
        FROM data
        GROUP BY %s , %s, %s, %s
    """ % ( x, y, crl_x, crl_y, v, x, y, crl_x, crl_y))
```

This query result is also important to browser. Because I must fetch all the data when the file is loading.

But I'm not sure how I can handle two queries in one get_data() function because I implement the query with cur.execute.
I was wondering if I can use cur.execute twice. I think that's wrong.
Then how can I implement two queries and fetch them as one **data** **parameter** and send **it** to browser?

Comment: What is the structure of `data` supposed to return? I assume you want it as a dictionary of Totals by Customer_type, Region, Corporate, and Belgium?

Comment: Year;Month;Customer ID;Customer type;Region;Collateral;Collateral type;Collateral value;Exposure amount
2005;1;10000;Retail;Sweden;0;;;376 847
2005;1;10001;Retail;Sweden;0;;;342 092
2005;1;10002;Retail;Sweden;1; 1    ;4 290 000;3 590 250

Comment: This is a piece of data.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is `data` that should be returned by the function? I see that you have a line that says `data = {'Total': 0}` so I'm making the assumption that you want the `get_data` function to return a dictionary.